# Unity performance for state machines: delegates or conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm not an expert when it's about CPU optimization, but I read that conditions in general are bad because the CPU is not able to optimize the running code if it could constantly change (even if it doesn't). So here's my take on Unity and state machines:

Very often you have an Update method that does different things depending on which state your MonoBehaviour currently is. Now, you could do it like this:

```
// this is only called once when the state switches
private void switchState(State newState) {
  state = newState;
}
private void Update() {
  switch(state) {
    case IDLE:
      doIdle();
      break;
    case ATTACKING:
      doAttack();
      break;
  // [...]
  }
}
```

Or you could do this:

```
// this is only called once when the state switches
private void switchState(State newState) {
  switch(newState) {
    case IDLE:
      _stateUpdateDelegate = doIdle;
      break;
    case ATTACKING:
      _stateUpdateDelegate = doAttack;
      break;
// [...]
  }
}
private void Update() {
  _stateUpdateDelegate();
}
```

Now, my question is not about how state machines should work, but rather what's faster in a real-time scenario. I also know the "don't do pre-optimizations" stuff and so on, that's also not the scope of this question. So my question is: what's faster and why (and where can I learn more about such things)?

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a look at [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) -> instead of using `Update` at all only run a Coroutine when it is needed and which one you can still decide using a `switch`

Comment: I don't see significant issue in your situation. In both cases the performance depends on the CPU. The only difference is in the first snippet you are storing the value, apparently for later use

Comment: Maybe you should get a behavior tree asset off the asset store. These tend to have already solved that issue and let you get back to what you're good at: designing.